# Example of using Dynamic and DynamicModule from Wolfram site

Tags: dynamic

What this example code from https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html (under Applications section the first example) should teach us?

```
 (* Constrain the coordinates of a point to lie on a circle: *)

 DynamicModule[{p = {0, 1}}, 
 Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[], PointSize[0.1], 
   Point[Dynamic[p, (p = Normalize[#]) &]]}, ImageSize -> Tiny, 
  PlotRange -> 1.2]]
```

[image]

I see nothing dynamic on the output. Even when I use `p = {0, 1/2}` instead of `p = {0, 1}` the point does not lie on the circle (no normalization of point `p` occur).

Comment: If you enter the above and then double click (and then drag the black dot around), it moves, constrained to the circle.

Comment: This is really unexpected. They should have mention it in the description - i.e. what to do to test it.

Comment: It's a graphic object -- one way to interact with a graphics objects is use the mouse. But surely you are correct that it would be better to explain it!

Comment: I thought double clicking on static 2D was meant only for manually editing it. Unlike when using on 3D graphics to rotate scene.

Answer (score 1):

Another example work.

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, 
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
  Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[], PointSize[Large], 
    Dynamic[Point[Normalize[pt]]]}], Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]